# Dynamic creation of tables in mysql using python

Tags: python, mysql, django, dynamic

I need to do calculations on a CSV dataset and latter store that as a SQL table in a MySQL Database. I have been thinking to use Django, but I don't think it allows dynamic creation of models. One more information I would like to provide that I don't know the number of variables in that table. So my question is, how should I proceed?. I have been thinking to create my own crude function for performing SQL queries or using Django south. Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: What would be the purpose of having data of an unknown schema in a database? How should this data be queried?

Comment: Lets say I will store all variables as varchar

Comment: If you're using `Django >= 1.7`, you don't need to be using Django South for migrations. [Migrations Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/migrations/)

Answer (score 0):

I would store the user-submitted data in a separate database than your main Django MySQL database.

Since you're not sure what the structure of the CSV dataset will be, using a document store like CouchDB or MongoDB may be your best bet.

[An Introduction to Using CouchDB with Django](https://lethain.com/an-introduction-to-using-couchdb-with-django/)

[Using MongoDB with Django](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-django-mongo/)